# How to change drive numbers in Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, partitioning, google-chrome-os

I installed a dualboot of Chrome OS and Windows on my laptop. But whenever I create a partition in Windows (with any partitioning tools), the drive number will be messed up and result in unbootable.

The correct drive number for me is like this:

> Partition ###       Type              Size     Offset
>
> ---
>
> Partition      11   Unknown                   8 MB    32 KB
> Partition      6    Unknown                  512 B     8 MB
> Partition      7    Unknown                  1024 MB   8 MB
> Partition      9    Unknown                  512 B  1032 MB
> Partition      10   Unknown                  512 B  1032 MB
> Partition      2    Unknown                  32 MB  1034 MB
> Partition      4    Unknown                  32 MB  1066 MB
> Partition      8    Unknown                  16 MB  1098 MB
> Partition      12   System                   32 MB  1178 MB
> Partition      5    Unknown                4096 MB  1210 MB
> Partition      3    Unknown                4096 MB  5306 MB
> Partition      1    Unknown                  59 GB     9 GB
> Partition      13   Primary                  93 GB   68 GB
> Partition      14   Primary                  76 GB   162 GB

Above showed the drive numbers as **11,6,7,9,10...14.** But if I do ANY partition operations on Windows, such as creating a NTFS partition, all drive numbers will be re-ordered like **0,1,2,3,4...14**...

I am using grub as boot manager, which means that I can troubleshoot it easily; But the problem is, the Linux distro will be unbootable after the drive number change, regardless of the correction of grub configuration.

How I can change the so called drive number **showed above** in Windows? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps look for a partition manager that is Windows compatible that can do custom partition orders? Do you know what it is about the order Disk Management created that Linux doesn't like?

Comment: @music2myear Probably they have something somewhere configured using the `/dev/sdaX` names. _Disk Management_ reorders numbers and boom, it's now a different partition.